# Remove multiple columns from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

What's the correct way to remove multiple columns from a data.table?  I'm currently using the code below, but was getting unexpected behavior when I accidentally repeated one of the column names.  I wasn't sure if this was a bug, or if I shouldn't be removing columns this way.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(x = letters, y = letters, z = letters)
DT[ ,c("x","y") := NULL]
names(DT)
[1] "z"
```

The above works fine, but

```
DT <- data.table(x = letters, y = letters, z = letters)
DT[ ,c("x","x") := NULL]
names(DT)
[1] "z"
```

Comment: +1. Interesting find. If you delete two "y"s, you get "x" left over. And if you delete two "z"s it crashes!

Comment: For now you could wrap the LHS of the `:=` assignment in a call to `unique()` (i.e. use `DT[ ,unique(c("x","x")) := NULL]`) to be extra defensive. Since this seems like a **data.table** bug, I'd guess you'll only have to do that until Matthew Dowle moves that call to `unique()` (or something equivalent to it) inside of the `[.data.table()`

Comment: Good idea about unique.  Thanks.

Comment: Hello guys, perhaps you know why this [R] code does not work for me?
> **myCols <- c("Col1", "Col2")**
> **DT[, myCols:=NULL]**
Suppose that DT contains both columns

Comment: @MindaugasK I found a solution to that -- you still have to wrap you list of columns as a list for it to work. Change it to `DT[, c(myCols):=NULL]` and that should do the trick. See https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/articles/datatable-reference-semantics.html#e-multiple-columns-and

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This looks like a solid, reproducible bug.  It's been filed as [Bug #2791](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2791&group_id=240&atid=975).

It appears that repeating the column attempts to delete the subsequent columns.
If no columns remain, then R crashes.

---

**UPDATE** : Now fixed in v1.8.11. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> Assigning to the same column twice in the same query is now an error rather than a crash in some circumstances; e.g., DT[,c("B","B"):=NULL] (delete by reference the same column twice). Thanks to Ricardo ([#2751](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=240&aid=2751&atid=975)) and matt_k ([#2791](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2791&group_id=240&atid=975)) for reporting. Tests added.

Comment: I'd like to add that the dot syntax (which is used as a shortcut for list in some DT ops) will not work here, i.e. `DT[ , .("x","x") := NULL]` will fail. Seems like it has to be a vector of the names of the columns as strings.

Answer (score 25):

This Q has been answered but regard this as a side note.

I prefer the following syntax to drop multiple columns

```
DT[ ,`:=`(x = NULL, y = NULL)]
```

because it matches the one to add multiple columns (variables)

```
DT[ ,`:=`(x = letters, y = "Male")]
```

This also check for duplicated column names. So trying to drop `x` twice will throw an error message.